# entityMananger not working with Date parameter

Tags: hibernate, jpa, criteria, entitymanager, hibernate-entitymanager

Using EntityManager approach with Hibernate. Whenever using a date field query I am expecting it to look for date with complete date and time, but it only uses date not time.

```
 where cou0_.expiry_date>'22-Jan-16'
```

**spring config**

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com" />
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
        </property>
        <property name="jpaProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">${hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">${hibernate.cache.use_query_caches}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class">${hibernate.cache.region.factory_class}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.generate_statistics">${hibernate.generate_statistics}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.use_sql_comments">${hibernate.use_sql_comments}</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

**Props**

```
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto = update
hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
hibernate.c3p0.min_size = 5
hibernate.c3p0.max_size = 10
hibernate.c3p0.timeout = 300
hibernate.c3p0.max_statements = 50
hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period = 3000
hibernate.generate_statistics = true
hibernate.show_sql=true
hibernate.use_sql_comments=true
```

Column declared as

```
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "expiry_date")
    private Date expiryDate;
```

**Query Code**

```
Query query = getEntityManager().createQuery("from **** where c.expiryDate  > :expiryDate");
        Date now = new Date();
        now.setHours(8);
        System.out.println("Date--"+now);
        query.setParameter("expiryDate", now,TemporalType.TIMESTAMP);
        List<****> entity = query.getResultList();
```

Comment: Give a reason for marking -1

Comment: Your query shows "c.lastUpdated > :expiryDate" yet your mapping and what I assume is SQL shows "expiry_date"

Comment: thanks @Chris updated my question.

Comment: @Chris JPQL uses class properties (expiryDate), and is then translated to SQL, which uses column names (expiry_date).

Comment: @ankitkatiyar91 Which package is the class Date used in the query code? Is it java.util.Date, or java.sql.Date? Why do you use the deprecated setHours() method?

Comment: FWIW JPQL should start "SELECT {alias}". Not part of the problem but bad practice

Comment: @JBNizet  I ma using java.util.Date, setHours() was just to make sure that I m date has a hour. Removing that also gives same output.

Comment: @NeilStockton  added select doesn't make any difference. I am using hibernate as provider and it works fine with these queries.

Comment: As I said ... not part of the problem ... I said BAD PRACTICE to ignore what the JPA spec says

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was not with entity manager. It was with spy that I was using to trace the query. Spy have configurable property to show dates in format. I didn't configured it so it want using default format i.e. dd-MMM-yyyy